# Hide DIVs with the same name using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide all divs with the name "mask"

This is my **HTML**:

```
<div id="first">
 <div id="firsttest"></div>
  <div class="one onehelp">
   <div id="mask">
    <div id="onetip"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="Div5"></div>
   <div id="resultone"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="two twohelp">
   <div id="mask">
    <div id="twotip"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="Div6"></div>
   <div id="resulttwo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="three threehelp">
   <div id="mask">
    <div id="threetip"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="Div7"></div>
   <div id="resultthree"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to hide "mask" by using the JS code below but it didn't work for all divs, just for the first one.

```
var hidemask = document.getElementById("mask");
hidemask.style.display = "none";
```

Is there a way to hide them all by using pure Javascript. No jQuery.

Comment: duplicate ID not allowed in HTML. Use `class` instead.

Comment: An ID has to be unique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't be using duplicate ID's in HTML, consider changing it to a class.

If you change `id="mask"` to `class="mask"`, then you can do:

```
var hidemask = document.querySelectorAll(".mask");

for (var i = 0; i < hidemask.length; i++) {
    hidemask[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Or for browsers still in the stone age (IE7 and below), you can do:

```
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
    for (i in elems) {
        if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + 'mask' + ' ') > -1) {
            elems[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obligatory "document.querySelectorAll won't work in IE7" warning.

Comment: @JoeEnos Added an option for stone age browsers :)

Comment: @mattytommo Yep, I cringe every time I see that, but as far as I know that's the only way to do it. Gotta wonder why it took so long to get a way to select by class name.

Answer (score 2):

The `id` attribute must be unique per document. You can do what you want with a `class`, perhaps. So you would have multiple `div`s like so:

```
<div id="something" class="mask"></div>
```

Then you can do:

```
var divsWithMask = document.querySelectorAll(".mask");
for(var i = 0; i < divsWithMark.length; i++) {
    divsWithMak[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign same ID more than once.

But you can add an attribute class to div with id "mask" E.g.:

```
<div id="mask-or-something-else" class="mask">...</div>
```

And select all elements by this class:

```
var hidemask = document.getElementsByClassName("mask");
for(i = 0; i < hidemask.length; i++)
    hidemask[i].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Obligatory "document.getElementsByClassName won't work in IE8" warning.

Comment: you probably meant `getElementsByClassName`, not "getElementByClassName" (note the missing "s").